# sql server select first row from a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

```
a          b
1          23
1          2
1          7
2          9
2          11
```

I want to select the first row(order does not matter) from a "GROUP BY a" query , the result should be

```
a          b
1          23
2          9
```

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 how to write the query for this?

Comment: So `(1,2),(2,11)` would also be acceptable as order doesn't matter? (Or any other arbitrary `b` value per `a`)

Comment: Yes, I just need one row, no matter what it is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If as you indicated, order doesn't matter, any [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258901%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on `b` would be sufficient.

#### Example Using MIN

```
SELECT a, b = MIN(b)
FROM   YourTable
GROUP BY
       a
```

Comment: Thank you Lieven, but this selects only one particular value. What if there were more columns and we need to select whole ROW (as the title says)?

Comment: @dpelisek - A typical solution would be to add a rownumber to each row partitioned by the column(s) you want to group on and only select the ones where the rownumber equals 1. I have setup an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1588/3) to show the intent. **Edit** <duh>, I really should read other answers first. Remi posted something similar.

Comment: This is wrong. The solution finds the MIN and not the FIRST. The comment here above is much better.

Comment: @Matte - True but the order doesn't matter. OP should have restated the question. Any arbitrary value of b will do *(for OP as per comments)*

Answer (score 150):

```
select a,b
from (
select a,b,row_number() over(partition by a order by b desc) as roworder
from myTable
) temp
where roworder = 1
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: When there's only one other value to pull from the row from each group (as here), it's simpler to just use `MIN` or `MAX` (your example is equivalent to just selecting `MAX(b)`). Of course, for more columns, it makes more sense.

Comment: Though the query looks complex but gives the flexibility to select multiple columns.

Comment: Even if your column is not numeric MAX/MIN will work ;-)