# How to group by on selected column in sql?

Tags: sql-server

How to apply a group by condition in a selected column
I want to apply group by condition only on name field of the "userdata" table.

```
SELECT CAST(UserId AS varchar(255)) AS UserId,
       CAST(name AS varchar(255)) AS name,
       CAST(city AS varchar(255))
FROM "userdata"
WHERE name = 'Jhohn'
GROUP BY CAST(UserId AS varchar(255)),
         CAST(name AS varchar(255)),
         CAST(city AS varchar(255));
```

The result of the above is

```
userId  name       city 
1       jhon       florida
2       sam        new york
3       sam        wales
4       thomas     new york
```

Expected results:

```
userId  name       city 
1       jhon       florida
2       sam        new york
4       thomas     new york
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server select first row from a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344731/sql-server-select-first-row-from-a-group)?

Comment: How should that work? Which value of userID do you expect for "sam"? There a 2 and a 3. The same applies for the city field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of sql server select first row from a group? – Larnu  in the given link  the fields another than that to be grouped  is  required to be aggregated.

Comment: I want to skip 3rd row of first table

Comment: @Ocean You can see my answer below. Here Min() function is used to keep only to skip 3rd row and keep 1st row. You can use Max() function if you want to keep 3rd row and remove first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this using following code

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (UserId int, [Name] varchar(255), City varchar(255));
INSERT INTO @Table (UserId,[name], city)
VALUES(1,'Jhon', 'florida') 
,(2,'sam', 'New york')
,(3,'sam','wales')
,(4,'thomas','new york');

Select t.* from @Table t
inner join (
SELECT MIN(UserId) as UserId, Name
FROM   @Table
GROUP BY
       Name
)a on t.UserId = a.UserId
```

You can find the live demo [**Here**](https://rextester.com/BDXA60879)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` like following to achieve what you are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
       SELECT userid, 
           NAME, 
           city, 
           Row_number() OVER(partition BY NAME ORDER BY id) RN 
    FROM   userdata 
    )T
    WHERE  T.RN= 1
```

I am not sure why you are casting `VARCHAR` data again to `VARCHAR`? and you are putting a where condition in you sample query which will filter the records and you will not get all the records.

Comment: where clause will execute before select statement and you alias RN in select statement. I am consfused :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like the below one.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (UserId int, [Name] varchar(255), City varchar(255));
INSERT INTO @Table (UserId,[name], city)
VALUES(1,'Jhon', 'florida') 
,(2,'sam', 'New york')
,(3,'sam','wales')
,(4,'thomas','new york');

SELECT sq.userId, sq.Name, sq.City
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Name ORDER BY t.UserId) AS RNo
    FROM @Table AS t
) AS sq
WHERE sq.RNo = 1
```