# Take first row after group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Does anyone know how to take always the first row after group by in SQL Server? Look on the screenshot for better explanation:

```
Result after select:
+------+---------+------+
| NAME | CAR     | AGE  |
+------+---------+------+
| Alex | BMW     | 5    |
+------+---------+------+
| Alex | Audi    | 2    |
+------+---------+------+
| Tom  | VW      | 10   |
+------+---------+------+
| Tom  | Renault | 4    |
+------+---------+------+
| Tom  | Peugeot | 2    |
+------+---------+------+

Expected result after group by:
+------+-----+
| NAME | CAR |
+------+-----+
| Alex | BMW |
+------+-----+
| Tom  | VW  |
+------+-----+
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344731/sql-server-select-first-row-from-a-group

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, but I have to say it is pain to create a table only with chars. But now I have it :-).

Comment: There is no such thing as a first row when an ordering hasn't been applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function with `PARTITION_BY` clause. This function assigns a sequential integer to each row within the partition of a result set. The row number starts with 1 for the first row in each partition.
After that, you can use the `where` clause to select rows that have row numbers as 1.

You can follow [this article](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) for a better understanding.

Below is just an example  (As I don't know how your query works):

```sql
select *
from
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) row_num, 
        *
       from(
         -- your main group by query
     )
)
where row_num=1
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw this method also in the other posts, but I think I go the GROUP BY way.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to get the top 1 record for each person using the below query, let me know if this works for you.
SELECT * FROM `car_owners` GROUP BY person_name;

let me know if you want to order the records in alphabetical order ASC or DESC and then GROUP BY them

Thank You
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KPXe.png)

Comment: :-) Thank you for the image, but do I have a guaranty that GROUP BY takes always the first row? That is the reason why I am asking. What is if my table has three columns an I want to have two columns as a result? I modified my table in my main question.

Comment: Yes, it can get the first record (car) of every person, and guarantee only depending on the order of the records stored in db.

Comment: Thank you, thats the answer what I needed!

Comment: Thank You, happy helping you @user1966102, please upvote this answer, to help others on StackOverflow